# Is the for loop in my code the speed bottleneck?

Tags: python, performance, for-loop

The following code looks through 2500 markdown files with a total of 76475 lines, to check each one for the presence of two strings.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# encoding: utf-8

import re
import os

zettelkasten = '/Users/will/Dropbox/zettelkasten'

def zsearch(s, *args):
    for x in args:
        r = (r"(?=.* " + x + ")")
        p = re.search(r, s, re.IGNORECASE)
        if p is None:
            return None
    return s

for filename in os.listdir(zettelkasten):
    if filename.endswith('.md'):
        with open(os.path.join(zettelkasten, filename),"r") as fp:
            for line in fp:
                result_line = zsearch(line, "COVID", "vaccine")
                if result_line != None:
                    UUID = filename[-15:-3]
                    print(f'›[[{UUID}]] OR', end=" ")
```

This correctly gives output like:

```
›[[202202121717]] OR ›[[202003311814]] OR
```

, but it takes almost two seconds to run on my machine, which I think is much too slow. What, if anything, can be done to make it faster?

Comment: from glancing over the code: why not read the file as a whole (instead of line by line) and use `re.matchiter`? you construct a new regex pattern for each line in each file. that pattern is static (you might even use `re.compile`).

Comment: The reason for reading line by line is that I want to return where the search terms appear in a single line and not anywhere in the file. Ideally, I'd like to search to file and find occurrences of the two search terms, maybe within ten words, even if in separate lines. But I'll start here and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main bottleneck is the regular expressions you're building.

If we `print(f"{r=}")` inside the `zsearch` function:

```
>>> zsearch("line line covid line", "COVID", "vaccine")
r='(?=.* COVID)'
r='(?=.* vaccine)'
```

The `(?=.*)` lookahead is what is causing the slowdown - and it's also not needed.

You can achieve the same result by searching for:

```
r=' COVID'
r=' vaccine'
```

Comment: Making the change you suggested took the time to execute from almost 2 sec. to .3 sec. Yahoo!! No speed difference when I look for 3 terms instead of two. Thank you @KarlT